# How to optimize the code after write a file successfully

Tags: swift, pdfkit

Create Pdf

I am Working on create a pdf multiple image unlimited images but the main issue is pdfKit after write not release the memory then the issue is app crashed after 1 GB Exceed Can anyone to help me to image to pdf Unlimited Images. i have using recursive function to release memory but in my case memory not relase i have shared the code kidly help

```
 func createPdfRecursiveFunction(image:UIImage,imageData:[UIImage],name:String)
    {
        
        autoreleasepool(invoking: {
            let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: image)!
        pdfdocument.insert(pdfPage, at: ImagesCount)
        if ImagesCount == (imageData.count - 1)
        {
            print("Write Successfully")
        }else{
            ImagesCount += 1
            if ImagesCount == (imageData.count - 1)
            {
                self.getAllImage.removeAll()
                self.imagedata.removeAll()
                print("Write Successfully")
                let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                var outputURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("PDFReader")
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: outputURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                    outputURL = outputURL.appendingPathComponent("\(name).pdf")
                }catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                _ = autoreleasepool
                   {
                pdfdocument.write(to: outputURL)
                   }
               
            }else{
                createPdfRecursiveFunction(image: imagedata[ImagesCount], imageData: imageData, name: name)
            }
        }})
    }
```

Comment: Why using recursivity and not just a simple loop ? If you want the function to be recursive you may try to create a PDF for the first image then pass it in the recursive func. But creating autorelease pool that create inside other pools can only leads to memory exhaust.

Comment: Why the PDFBox label?

Comment: autorelease pools can be recursive, but since you are invoking the recursive call before the autorelease pool exits, that means the memory from the outer calls is not released until all the recursive calls finish, i.e. you still have everything in memory.  As mentioned, a loop would be much more obvious, and you could use a pool on each loop iteration, to flush out any unneeded memory before the next iteration.  The entire pdfdocument is still in memory though before you write it; not sure you can avoid that.  The creation of the PDFPage is all you can wrap with a pool.

Comment: I m using recursive for the memory released and I used autoreleasedpool for the memory release in this scenario memory not released so that's why i m used autoreleasepool for every iteration. Can you please write a code to figure what is the problem in my code

Note: Released memory in case after dismiss the controller then pdfKit memory released so I m stuck in this scenario Thank you Everyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are recursively calling the createPdfRecursiveFunction from within the autorelease block itself, which means the block wont reach the end and drain until all images have been processed.

Either call the createPdfRecursiveFunction just after the end of the autorelease block, or separate your code so that the pdf work is done in a separate function with an autorelease block e.g.

```
createPdfRecursiveFunction() {
   if imageToBeWritten {addImageToPDF(image)}
}

addImageToPDF(image:UIImage) {
    @autoreleasepool {
      // Add image to pdf code here
    }
}
```